# How to avoid refreshing the cache when creating a new Fiori tile

Tags: sap-fiori

When creating a new SAP Fiori tile and releasing our DEV transport, we always need to run the `/UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES` program for the tile to appear in our TEST environment.

What is the procedure we should follow when creating new Tiles?

Comment: Sounds like you probably have the metadata cache turned on in your test environment. That's fine, but then you'll just have to run the cache invalidation whenever you move things up the landscape.

Answer (score 1):

As per SAP, you need to run that program after a change in Catalog/Group/Tile. 
Reference: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2362875

Anyway, you just have to run it once and all users should be good. Did I understand it wrong?